# Cassandra dynamic user permissions management

Tags: authorization, cassandra

My question is whether Cassandra enables the below described scenario out-of-the-box.

The scenario:

1. Data owner - a "super-user" who wants to share some data in Cassandra with other users.
2. End user - a regular user who requests access to some subset of data
3. Cloud provider - hosts the Cassandra data store on behalf of the Data owner.

I know it is possible to define some restrictions on accessing data using configuration files ([see reference](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/configuration/authentication)). My question is if it is possible to dynamically allow the Data owner to update those access rights (e.g. add/remove users to the access list) by remotely contacting the Cassandra cluster?

Answer (score 1):

As of Cassandra v1.2.2 (i think) user management is much improved.

A cloud provider could host multiple Cassandra clusters and grant super user access to data owners. Super users have access to all keyspaces on the cluster.

The data owners in turn could create keyspaces and grant access to an entire keyspace to end users.
http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/security/native_authentication

This can all be done with CQL, the configuration files for user access are no longer needed.